# NodeJS Promises consume too much memory?

Tags: node.js, performance, memory-leaks, comparison

I'm trying to analyze how effective the NodeJS is in handling async functions.

I have the NodeJS script below to initiate 10 millions of Promises which will sleep for 2 seconds to simulate an intensive backend API calls. The script run for a while (~30s), consumed up to 4096 MB of ram and threw `JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

1. Does the Promises really consume that much memory ?
2. How come the NodeJS is supposed to be good for I/O intensive operations when it uses too much memory ?
3. Golang only uses 10MB of memory to handle 100 millions of Go Routines, is Golang even better than NodeJS in handling I/O intensive operations ?

```
const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const fakeAPICall = async (i) => {
  await sleep(2000);
  return i;
};

const NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS = 1e7;
console.time(`${NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS} executions:`);

[...Array(NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS).keys()].forEach((i) => {
  fakeAPICall(i).then((r) => {
    if (r === NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS - 1) {
      console.timeEnd(`${NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS} executions:`);
    }
  });
});
```

ERROR

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[41215:0x10281b000]    36071 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4095.5 (4100.9) -> 4095.3 (4105.7) MB, 5864.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 1.3 ms in 2767 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 7190 ms) (average mu = 0.296, current mu = 0.[41215:0x10281b000]    44534 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4096.3 (4104.7) -> 4096.3 (4105.7) MB, 8461.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.140, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x100098870 node::Abort() [/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000989eb node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node]
 3: 0x1001a6d55 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001a6cff v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node]
 5: 0x1002dea5b v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node]
 6: 0x100316819 v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs has a default memory limit which can be changed with the `--max_old_space_size=<memory in MB>` NODE option;

> I have the NodeJS script below to initiate **10 millions** of Promises

Not even close. There are about 50 million of them.

```js
const sleep = async (ms) => { // redundant async - Promise#1
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); // Promise#2
}

const fakeAPICall = async (i) => { // async - Promise#3
  await sleep(2000); // await - Promise#4
  return i;
};

const NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS = 1e7;

console.time(`${NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS} executions:`);

for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS; i++) {
  fakeAPICall(i).then((r) => { // then - Promise#5
    if (r === NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS - 1) {
      console.timeEnd(`${NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS} executions:`);
    }
  });
}
```

In each iteration, you actually create at least 5 promises and one generator, so you have 50 million promises and a huge amount of other objects in memory. This is a lot since they are pure JS objects written in JS and of course, they consume more memory than low-level precompiled languages. Node is not about low memory consumption, but memory becomes the bottleneck in your case.
Promises are made for ease of use, if you need memory optimization - pure callbacks can be cheaper.

Here we create 10M promises:

```js
const NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS = 5_000_000;

console.log(`Start `, NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS);

const sleep = (ms, i) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms, I)); // Promise#1

console.time(`${NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS} executions`);

for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS; i++) {
  sleep(2000, i).then((r) => { // then - Promise#2
    if (r === NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS - 1) {
      console.timeEnd(`${NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS} executions`);
    }
  });
}
```

Memory (2.6 GB):

```
Start  5000000
{
  rss: '2.72 GB',
  heapTotal: '2.68 GB',
  heapUsed: '2.6 GB',
  external: '308 kB',
  arrayBuffers: '10.4 kB'
}
5000000 executions: 24.776s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I ran this using nodejs v20 & got an OOM error...
#
# Fatal javascript OOM in MemoryChunk allocation failed during deserialization.
#

Comment: v19 has a FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: You haven't changed the default memory limit. The first script requires up to 10GB of RAM limit. Either increase the memory limit by adding --max_old_space_size=10000 startup argument or reduce the number of iterations by setting NUM_OF_EXECUTIONS = 1_000_000